# Pandas tokening error with iteration

Tags: windows, pandas, iteration

I have this line in my ipython note book:

for sourceCSV in outFileList:

```
for df in pd.read_csv(sourceCSV, chunksize=chunksize, iterator=True, encoding='utf-8')
```

it is supposed to add two csv files 10,000 rows each, and add them to a data frame. It returns the tokenizing error (CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string starting at line 10000). It happens when reading the last line of the second file. I am running the code in windows, we ran it in Mac and we didn't have this problem. Should I change read_CSV options?

Comment: Can you try this `for df in pd.read_csv(sourceCSV, chunksize=chunksize, iterator=True, encoding='utf-8', error_bad_line=False)`

Comment: I did so, it returns the same error. I think the EOF problem can be also due to my system setting. I ran this code in Mac and it was just fine. It might be the read-write permission issue on my computer.